# (vba) Is it possible to compare a column of data from an Access table to a column of data in an Excel table without opening the Excel document?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, compare

I'd like to know if there's a way (using Access VBA) to check a column of dates in an Excel sheet (theres only one worksheet) without opening the file itself, and then compare it to a column of dates in an Access table.

**Clarification:**  I apologize for the vagueness of my terminology.  When I said "without opening the excel file" I was referring to the act of getting the information from the excel file without the user ever seeing it pop up on their screen or task bar.

**Clarification 2:** To clear up any confusion, the use of VBA to accomplish this is preferred but certainly not required.  I'm also fine with Access macros, and SQL (provided its deployed from VBA), and other things.  Anything so long as it can be run directly from Access.

Extra info:
The dates in both instances should always be in the same order.  The only things I'm concerned with are a.) not having to resort to opening the excel document, b.) Checking if the data from both sources are the same.  i.e. true if they're exactly the same, false if there is even one slight difference.

Comment: How do you intend to read the contents of something on a disk drive without "opening" that file in some way.  (I guess it depends on what you mean by "open".  i.e. do you mean answers must exclude a `Workbooks.Open` statement?  Or do you only want to exclude a **visible to the user** opening of the file?  Or do you really mean that the file must not be opened in any way and thus the contents of the file cannot be examined by the code?)

Comment: Hey there.  What I meant was I don't want it to be visible to the user.  Sorry, I realized this might be confusing a few hours after I posted it last night.  What I actually meant was open it sort of in the background without ever showing the user the excel window.

Comment: And the other question is ... why **must** it be VBA and answers should not suggest better methods?  I really think the first sentence of your question should either be deleted (as there are already two good answers which don't require VBA [although both could easily be used with an additional VBA "wrapper" just to satisfy the restriction]) or expanded to indicate **why** that restriction has to exist and what the VBA code is / is not permitted to do (e.g. is a minimal wrapper around a simple query such as suggested by Parfait allowed or not?).

Comment: Maybe I should clarify more.  I apologize.  I didn't mean VBA is the only tool that one can use.  I just assumed it was the most flexible.  If it involves a macro or some SQL coding that can be run from VBA, I'm ok with that too.  Really, anything is acceptable as long as the task can be run directly and automatically from Access.

The top message in my post is merely to ward away people who might say things like "just import the excel data into access" or "copy and paste" or anything to that effect.

Comment: I suggest you reword your question to get rid of that first sentence.  And, in order to get rid of the "Too Broad" hold, perhaps work out what your issue is - is it that you are trying to work out how to access the contents of an Excel spreadsheet without the user seeing Excel being opened?  Or is it, once you have access to the contents of the sheet, how to compare the two sets of information (Excel -v- Access) to see if there are differences?  (If both issues exist, I suggest you narrow the question to how to access the spreadsheet, and then create another question for how to compare.)

Comment: Note:  You can edit your question as much as you like (you don't have to just add "Clarifications" to it), but it is a very good idea not to change it so that any existing answers are no longer appropriate.  (So if you narrowed this question down to "How can I access the contents of an Excel spreadsheet within Access", then both the linked table answer and the Access query answer will both still be appropriate (and, I believe, answer the question quite well - linked table is virtually the same as any other Access table, and the Access SQL query can be invoked in VBA just like any other query))

Comment: I apologize for not posting up to this sites standards! I will take your advice and remove the first line. That being said, if I could use a linked table for my specific needs, I would have done so. You did sum up the question however. I need to be able to pull a group of information from Excel without letting the user see what is happening. I know that you can pull and read information from a database table by using recordsets, and that the recordset method is far more efficient than using dlookup... ideally I'd like some kind of equivalent method for pulling information from an Excel file.

Comment: If I clarify it in this way though, the below answers will become irrelevant I'm afraid. (They already were but I'm trying to comply with your guidelines).

Comment: So you don't want the users to even be able to see the existence of a (linked) table in the database, or the existence of a stored query that links to a spreadsheet?  Nor even create a temporary query within your VBA code to access the spreadsheet?  (I'm not trying to be difficult with these questions - I just really don't understand what the restrictions are that you are working under.)

Comment: I don't feel like the reason for the restriction should be relevant (although I'm fully aware you're just trying to see if there is a better way to do this).  But the reason why it can't be linked is due to network limitations.  (see next post)

Comment: As I've mentioned, there is a local table that needs comparing to.  Its data is nearly always going to be identical to the excel sheet.  I wouldn't have asked any of this if I could have made that table a linked one in the first place. The reason why I cant do that is because it would cause all the functions that rely on it to take an unreasonable amount of time to run.  Making it a local table was the only way to keep load times realistic.

Comment: I didn't want to have to explain it because then we'd get all up into the design that its based on and trying to figure out a way to redesign the process from the ground up... and then we'd end up back here anyway.  I've explored my options quite thoroughly.  That's all.  :)

Answer (score 1):

While you may not write code to open the file yourself the file will be opened by the possible methods in order to read it I believe.

The simplest way to compare Excel data to MS Access in my opinion is to created a Linked table to the sheet and then compare using a sql query.

I would probably make a calculated column on the end of each table/excelTable with every field concatenated with a pipe '|' and compare this 'key'.

Note: when you open the linked table the file is opened in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you do not need VBA but can connect to Excel workbooks even csv/txt files in an Access SQL query. Below assumes Excel data maintains column headers with data beginning in cell A1.

```sql
SELECT acc.*, xl.*
FROM myAccessTable acc
INNER JOIN
    [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;Database=C:\Path\To\Workbook.xlsx].[SHEEETNAME$] xl
ON acc.[DateColumn] = xl.[DateColumn];
```